# custom nifi processor - writing of flow file

Tags: java, scala, apache-nifi

I want to create a custom `NiFi` processor which can read `ESRi ASCII grid files` and return `CSV` like representation with some metadata per file and geo-referenced user data in WKT format.

Unfortunately, the parsed result is not written back as an updated flow file.

https://github.com/geoHeil/geomesa-nifi/blob/rasterAsciiGridToWKT/geomesa-nifi-processors/src/main/scala/org/geomesa/nifi/geo/AsciiGrid2WKT.scala#L71-L107 is my try at making this happen in NiFi.

Unfortunately, only the original files are returned. The converted output is not persisted.

When trying to adapt it to manually serialize some CSV strings like:

```
  val lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator")
  val csvResult = result.map(p => p.productIterator.map{
    case Some(value) => value
    case None => ""
    case rest => rest
  }.mkString(";")).mkString(lineSep)

  var output = session.write(flowFile, new OutputStreamCallback() {
    @throws[IOException]
    def process(outputStream: OutputStream): Unit = {
      IOUtils.write(csvResult, outputStream, "UTF-8")
    }
  })
```

still no flowflies are written. Either the issue from above persists or I get Stream not closed exceptions for the outputStream.

It must be a tiny bit which is missing, but I can't seem to find the missing bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each session method that changes flow file like session.write() returns a new version of file and you have to transfer this new version.

If you change your file in converterIngester() function, you have to return this new version to caller function to transfer to relationship.

Comment: I see, and should I manually serialize to csv as my dummy code outlines? or will wifi handle serialization of case classes to Avro for me?

Comment: You should so it yourself. For nifi the file content is just a binary stream. Probably you could check how across serialization done for database results in nifi https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/util/JdbcCommon.java